# TreeView Template: Binding returning null

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm trying to style a `TreeView` using [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752048.aspx) and everything was working fine until I tried to add bindings to my `DataContext`.  Namely, I replaced the `Fill` of the `Paths` for the arrows with a `MultiBinding` to the current theme.  Here's the relative code:

```
<Path x:Name="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Margin="1" Data="M 4 0 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z">
   <Path.Fill>
       <SolidColorBrush>
           <SolidColorBrush.Color>
               <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ThemeToColorConverter}"
                             ConverterParameter="Foreground">
                   <Binding Path="Themes" />
                   <Binding Path="ThemeIndex" />
               </MultiBinding>
           </SolidColorBrush.Color>
       </SolidColorBrush>
   </Path.Fill>
</Path>
```

I've set a breakpoint in the converter, and the problem seems to be that the two `Bindings` can't find their `Paths`, because they both send `null` into the converter.  However, I use this same code while setting the `Button` style earlier in the code, and the buttons show up perfectly.

The only thing I can think of is that, in the `TreeView Style`, the `Bindings` are pulling from a different source.  I just don't know how they would be doing that or how to fix it.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a binding exception in the output window?

Comment: Yeah, actually.  Here: `System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Themes; DataItem=null; target element is 'SolidColorBrush' (HashCode=31542128); target property is 'Color' (type 'Color')`

Comment: Okay, I think I might have it.  The `MultiBinding` is trying to pull from each `Item`'s `Source`.  Now how to fix it....

Comment: @Andy: By the way, thanks for the tip.  I never thought to look there, and it ended up solving my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got it, so I'm posting my solution so anyone else with the same problem can (hopefully) find it.  The problem was that the bindings were binding to the `TreeView Items`, not the `UserControl's DataContext`, so I named the `UserControl` and set the `Bindings' ElementNames` to that:

```
<Path x:Name="Collapsed" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
      Margin="1" Data="M 4 0 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z">
   <Path.Fill>
       <SolidColorBrush>
           <SolidColorBrush.Color>
               <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ThemeToColorConverter}"
                             ConverterParameter="Foreground">
                   <Binding ElementName="Control" Path="Themes" />
                   <Binding ElementName="Control" Path="ThemeIndex" />
               </MultiBinding>
           </SolidColorBrush.Color>
       </SolidColorBrush>
   </Path.Fill>
</Path>
```